# Libtorrent not working when loading infohash from json?

Tags: python, json, libtorrent

I am trying to make a python script that downloads just the metadata of a torrent given an infohash. This infohash is loaded from a json file, with the contents like such:

```
{"infohash":"someinfohash"}
```

If I manually encode the infohash into the link string, or I make it personally using a dictionary, like this:

```
link = 'magnet:?xt=urn:btih:someinfohash'
```

or like this:

```
foo = {}
foo['infohash'] = 'someinfohash'
link = 'magnet:?xt=urn:btih:' + foo['infohash']
```

I can always download the metadata, no problem. But for some reason, when I load it from a json file, it consistently times out.

```
thedata = open(sys.argv[1]).read()
thedata = json.loads(thedata)

ses = lt.session()

ses.listen_on(6881, 6891)

params = {
    'save_path': '.', # doesn't matter because we're only downloading metadata
}
link = 'magnet:?xt=urn:btih:' + thedata['infohash']

handle = lt.add_magnet_uri(ses, link, params)

ses.add_dht_router('dht.transmissionbt.com', 6881)
ses.add_dht_router('router.bittorrent.com', 6881)
ses.add_dht_router('router.utorrent.com', 6881)
ses.start_dht()

sys.stdout.write('Downloading metadata...')
sys.stdout.flush()
timeout = time.time()
while (not handle.has_metadata()):
    if (time.time() >= 300 + timeout):
        print 'timed out'
        sys.exit(1)
    time.sleep(1)
print 'done'

ses.pause()
```

If I check if the strings are equal, like so:

```
link = 'magnet:?xt=urn:btih:' + thedata['infohash']
link2 = 'magnet:?xt=urn:btih:someinfohash'
print link == link2
```

It prints true.

Does anybody have any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found what was wrong with it.

I got the idea to examine the programmer-friendly text representation of the json-generated dictionary as opposed to my one made manually.

```
thedata = open(sys.argv[1]).read()
thedata = json.loads(thedata)

print thedata

thedata = {}
thedata['infohash'] = 'someinfohash'

print thedata
```

What came up was this:

```
{u'infohash', u'someinfohash'}
{'infohash', 'someinfohash'}
```

Apparently the json-made dict was encoded in unicode, and this somehow prevented libtorrent from connecting to seeders. After un-unicoding all the keys and values, the script runs perfectly.